# What does poly function in lm formula mean or R?

Tags: r, lm, coefficients

I've a large number of datasets ​​of x, y, and z.

Ex)

```
x: 1,2,3,... (5000 datasets)
y: 4,6,7,... (5000 datasets)
z: 9,8,7,... (5000 datasets)
```

An anonymous angel in this community taught me how to draw a 3D scatter plot by telling me the code below.

```
lm(z~poly(x,y,degree = 2))
```

[image]

As a result of finding the R2 value of this formula using the summary function, 1.000 came out shockingly.
I tried understand it, but failed.

What does that formula mean?

Comment: The formula fits a 2nd degree polynomial in `x` and `y`. It expands to `x + x^2 + x*y + y + y^2`.

Comment: Sorry, it *would* expand to the polynomial in my previous comment only with `poly(etc, raw = TRUE)`.

Comment: Just adding information, R^2 is invariant to linear transformations of your covariates, so using `raw=TRUE`, or the default polynomials computed by `poly()` (orthogonal polynomials) will result in the same R^2.